# Java conditionals for JSON API Data Android App

Tags: java, android, json

I have a JSON Feed where I need to display data based on conditions.

My question is how do I write the below into conditionals for Android in Java to display the correct data:

- 1 match can only belong to 1 round
- 1 round can only belong to 1 competition.
- 1 competition can contain 1 or more rounds
- 1 round can contain 1 or more matches.

Demo data link [here](http://demo3317540.mockable.io/tomorrowMatchList)

Comment: Maybe it would be more fun for you to parse 775 KB and demonstrate a little intention trying to accomplish what you need?

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to give you the exact answer. but i will give you some idea.

First Create a **JSOnArray** for round and competition

```
JSONArray round = new JSONArray();
JSONArray regions = new JSONArray();
JSONArray competition = new JSONArray();
```

Then try to separate objects depend on type

```
try {
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject("{your json String}");
    JSONArray dataArray = data.getJSONArray("included");
    for (int i=0; i<dataArray.length(); i++){
        JSONObject singleItem  = (JSONObject) dataArray.get(i);
        String type = singleItem.getString("type");

        if (type.equals("rounds")){
            round.put(singleItem);
        }else if(type.equals("regions")){
            regions.put(singleItem);
        }else if (type.equals("competition")){
            competition.put(singleItem);
        }else {}

    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then you can do your validations